# How to show an alert in ios for paper out error from zebra printer?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to show an alert from my app. When my app is successfully connected with zebra printer and then if the printer doesnot have paper at the time of printing.. i want to show an alert in my app about the paper out error... please sunbmit your answers if anybody knows...

Answer (score 1):

What exactly you are looking for? Do you want to know the code for how to create and show an alert? or do you want to interact with printer and get the status so as to show alert?

If you are looking for code that shows an alert here you go..

```
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Printer Warning" message:@"Printer running out of paper" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
[alertView show];
```

Comment: While this answer is correct in terms of displaying an alert, it may have been better as a comment to seek clarification

Comment: @Paulw11 I started as a comment but then posted as an answer just to hightlight the code

Comment: You can highlight small sections of code in comments using back ticks `like this`

Comment: Hi Tamil.. i need to show the alert after my app interacted with zebra printer and if it doesnot have paper in it.

Answer (score 0):

have u used this block?

```
void (^completionhandler)(UIPrintInteractionController *, BOOL, NSError *) = ^(UIPrintInteractionController *print, BOOL completed, NSError *error)
        {
            if (!completed && error)
            {
                NSLog(@"%@", error.localisedDescription);
            }
        };
```

if any error occurs, the error will be logged and u can also use it in AlertView.

```
if(!completed && error)
{
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:error.localisedDescription cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtons:@"OK", nil];
    [alertview show];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply... but i want to show the alert of paper out in my app when the zebra printer doesnot have paper in it... do i have to use any specific cpcl commands for that in my code?